# Transfer iframe content to a new empty iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

So basicly i got one Big iframe without any thing in it.. and then ive used the youtube api to search for youtube videos which comes in a new iframe. So i wonder if its possible to transfer one iframe with a video in it to another without any.. 
Here is a fiddle but of some reason i can't see the bigger player which i can see in my own website.. https://jsfiddle.net/74wfou72/4/

```
<div id ="player">  </div>
<iframe  class = "videon" height = "80" width = "120" frameborder = "0" 
     src ="//www.youtube.com/embed/bHQqvYy5KYo" showinfo = 0 controls=0 ></iframe>
```

with some java on the player too which you can see in the fiddle..

Thankfull for any help! (:

Comment: The onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function is called before it is defined as you have the JavaScript set to run onLoad in the jsfiddle and the API is loaded and ready by then so it has already tried calling the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function. This one works, it is set to put the script in <head>, it also works in <body>. https://jsfiddle.net/74wfou72/3/

Comment: I'm also not sure if you are wanting two players or not? The YouTube API will replace the <div id="player"> with an iFrame containing the Player.

Comment: oh yeah that is how i should look il update it, thanks! @spaceman

Comment: i want to send the video from the small iframe to the player without any video in it @spaceman

Comment: If you only want the one video, why not load it in the player initially and just remove the smaller video from the HTML in the first place? Like https://jsfiddle.net/74wfou72/5/. I set the videoId to the Id of the YouTube video you want to play.

Comment: That's the problem i can't just set a video there because i want it to be any video that i search for. So i got this youtube search list where i can search for a youtube video then it displays as a small iframe... Then i want to be able to play that small iframe on this bigger one. @spaceman

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/74wfou72/6/ ? As long as the video id is always the end of the URL that will work. If you are just displaying the video and not using the API to play/pause etc you could just copy the src of the small into the src of a bigger iFrame https://jsfiddle.net/74wfou72/7/ like that.

Comment: That first fiddle (6) was just what i looked for thanks alot, make it the answer and i will accept it as soon as possible! @spaceman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener to a button which will extract the ID from the smaller iFrame and then use the YouTube API to create the bigger iFrame.

Example:

```
document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var id = document.querySelector('.videon').getAttribute('src').split('/');
    id = id[id.length - 1];
    play(id);
});

var apiReady = false;
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    apiReady = true;
}

function play(id) {
    if(apiReady) {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: id,
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If the API hasn't loaded, `apiReady` will be false and the YouTube player won't be created. You could add an error for that scenario if you wanted as feedback to the user.

The ID of the YouTube video needs to be the final parameter of the URL otherwise it won't work either.

Full coded example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/74wfou72/8/)